# whats the general process for using a smart card in truecrypt?

Tags: windows, truecrypt, smartcard

I'm a little confused with how to deploy truecrypt our environment

I purchased a few smartcards (ACOS5) that are supposedly compatible with truecrypt

however i'm unable to make it all work due to lack of drivers and smartcard tooling

my question to serverfault is what should I expect?  i've been led to believe that I need to purchase a smartcard SDK in order to get the drivers? other cards I've investigated also have SDK's

i'm finding information about how to setup smartcards very confusing - very little information and very few sources for buying low volume cards

is the standard procedure to purchase a smart card SDK if you're not developing software - meaning if you just need the tooling/DLLs/drivers?

how does all this fit together?